# Bode Plot Asymptotic Approach Questions

Tags: bode-plot

Consider the step-by-step asymptotic approach for drawing Bode plots given on the last page [here](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~sullivan/22files/Bode_plots.pdf). I had two questions about using this approach by hand (instead of adding individual graphs to find the composite graph):

1. What exactly does the highlighted part below mean? Does "it" (for the limit direction) refer to the network function \$H\$, \$jw\$ (= \$s\$), or something else? If it's \$s\$, isn't \$s\$ *always* an imaginary number with a positive imaginary part (since \$\omega > 0\$)?[image: Phase when limit is 0]
2. How would you draw the Bode (magnitude and phase) plot if there were multiple different (not repeated) factors in the network function having the same break frequency—e.g. \$G_v = \frac{s^2 + 1}{s^2 + 0.5s + 1}\$, which has a quadratic zero *and* a quadratic pole with the same break frequency, 1 rad/s? Going left to right, I thought the slope (in the magnitude plot) would change by +40 dB/decade (due to the quadratic zero) and −40 dB/decade (due to the quadratic pole) at \$\omega\$ = 1 rad/s, effectively "cancelling" each other out and producing **no change**. However, [WolframAlpha suggests otherwise](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Bode%20plot%20(s**2%20%2B%201)%2F(s**2%20%2B%200.5s%20%2B%201)). Why isn't the magnitude plot at \$\omega\$ = 1 rad/s just a straight line (continued from the left) with **zero change**? (Compare the lower right figure mentioned [here](http://web.mit.edu/2.010/www_f00/psets/hw2_dir/tutor2_dir/tut2_e.html).)

Comment: The inversion of ratios is key to understanding how phase inverts, and steep slope phase change occurs at resonance. The numerator and denominator phase changes are opposite and cancel only at resonance

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, thanks for your comment, but that wasn't really my doubt. (I have reworded question 2 to make it clearer. Sorry for that!)